# Is this a unit test or integration test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am learning how to create a unit test in Spring Boot JPA with JUnit and Mockito

I have done up a test class,

```
public void testInsertionMethod() throws Exception {

    String URI = "/insertionURL";
    ShoppingList list = new ShoppingList (3, new Fruit(1), new Vegetable(1));
    String inputJson= this.jsonConversionMethod(list);

    Assert.assertEquals(1, list.getNumOfItems());
    Assert.assertEquals(1, list.getFruit().getFruitId);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, list.getVegetable.getVegetableId());

    Mockito.when(shoppingListSvc.save(Mockito.any(ShoppingList.class))).thenReturn(list);

    MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URI).param("fruitId", "1").param("vegId", "1"). accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(inputJson).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();

    MockHttpServletResponse mockHttpServletResponse = mvcResult.getResponse();
    String jsonOutput = mockHttpServletResponse.getContentAsString();
    assertThat(outputJson).isEqualTo(inputJson);
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), mockHttpServletResponse.getStatus());

}
```

Can anyone advise on how I can improve my unit testing? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: A unit test is, as the name suggests, when you test a "unit". A class or a piece of code that is isolated from external dependencies and that's tested on its own. As soon as you need to mock behaviour for other dependencies it stops being a simple unit test. Other than that, what is your question? If you're looking for improvements on your test, you can check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's a component test. Also your test class is probably annotated with

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
```

cause you are using mockMvc to mock a call to endpoint.

In my opinion it does not make sense to do this part

```
 Assert.assertEquals(1, list.getNumOfItems());
 Assert.assertEquals(1, list.getFruit().getFruitId);
 Assert.assertEquals(1, list.getVegetable.getVegetableId());
```

cause you created this object in the test and you know what did you put there. The only thing you should be interested in is what your endpoint returns. You can check it as you already do via comparing inputJson and outputJson or do it like this:

```
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", equalTo(...)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstName", notNullValue()))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastName").isNotEmpty())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email", equalTo(...)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.partnerId", equalTo(...)));
```

Depends on what is important for you to check. E.g. if your response returns id which is generated by some internal class/method you will not be able to construct such inputJson cause you cannot predict which id will be returned. In this case you are able to check that id is not empty

```
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").isNotEmpty())
```

Comment: thank you for your input and advice. another question i have is, then when do exceptions come into play here? like NullPointerException etc. how do i know when I'll need it?

Comment: Well , that part I would test in unit tests.. E.g. your service cannot find something by Id and you may get EntityNotFoundException, or some object is null and you may get NPE. In unit tests you are checking that  `EntityNotFoundException exception = assertThrows(EntityNotFoundException.class, () -> service.getSomething(WRONG_ID));`  And you can then check message `  assertEquals(exception.getMessage(), MessageFormat.format("Entity with id {0} not found.", WRONG_ID));` And also verify that further methods were not called e.g. `verify(anotherService, never()).save(any());`